# Given N, generate all sequences that start with 0 and end with N, and the diff between neighboring elements are power of 2 - in Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I had the question in the title and I don't know how to optimize the solution with DP.
For example, given N=5, all the sequences will be:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5]
[0 1 2 3 5]
[0 1 2 4 5]
[0 1 3 4 5]
[0 1 3 5]
[0 1 5]
[0 2 3 4 5]
[0 2 3 5]
[0 2 4 5]
[0 4 5]
```

I solved it using Recursion https://play.golang.org/p/i2aCQBF01m_T, there are many calculation duplicates and I don't have an idea how to dynamic program it.

For example in:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5]
[0 1 3 4 5]
```

the end section `3 4 5` is calculated twice.

I thought of having a map like so `map[int][][]int` but the space consumption seemed to me the wrong way to go.

Comment: If you only want to *count* these sequences, then I'm sure DP will speed things up a lot. But if you need to *print* all of them, then I don't think it will help at all. It seems to me that your recursive code will expend much less computational effort in generating these sequences than in printing them out. By the way, could you please edit your question to insert the recursive code you wrote instead of linking to another site?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getSeqs(n) {
  let seqs = [[0]]
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    seqs.push([])
    for (let j = 1; j <= i; j *= 2) {
      seqs[i] = seqs[i].concat(seqs[i - j].map(t => t * 10 + i))
    }
  }
  return seqs[n].map(t => '0' + t)
}

console.log(getSeqs(5))
```